# ADO.Net Entity Data Model does not decorate fields with required attribute

Tags: entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to reverse engineer a SQL Server database to an Entity Framework Data Model (version 6.0). The classes are generated fine, but required fields are not decorated as such. As a result the validation is not working (in an MVC 5 web application).
Is there a way to make the model generate these attributes automatically or do I have to manually write meta data classes for all my entities?

Comment: How are you trying to reverse engineer it?  What style are you using? (edmx? code first?), why are you depending on the data model to validate your UI?

Comment: I am using edmx. I believed that the emdx generated classes would contain the appropriate attributes (such as max length, required etc.) to make it quicker to build CRUD interfaces.

Comment: It's not recommended that you use the data model directly in the user interface.  One reason is that data model requirements may be different than your UI requirements.  Also, the attributes used for Max length and what not are different in EF vs MVC.  You should use a view model instead.

Comment: So there's no automatic way to generate such classes from a database?

Comment: You could try using scaffolding.  This is for MVC4, so the conversion to dbcontext doesn't apply, but it may help http://ozkary.blogspot.com/2012/10/database-first-development-with-aspnet.html

Answer (score 1):

Speaking to your question, What are your assumptions for required fields? Do you mean non-nullable?

EF should make any field that is marked as not null as either a non-nullable value type (int, decimal, bool, etc.) or it will make fields required via xml validation. EF doesn't typically add attributes.

MVC will automatically make any value types required, no attribute is required.  For strings or other possible nullable types, then you will either need "buddy classes" to add the attributes you need, or you use view models.

Comment: Yes my problem is with string fields. I will go down the meta data classes way I guess.